# Windows 7 does not accept broadcasts from ip address 0.0.0.1

Tags: networking, windows-7, ip-address, broadcast

we have little network devices which are shipped with IP address 0.0.0.1 to *ensure* that they never collide with any other device in their new environment (thus none of the 10.x.x.x, 172.16.x.x or 192.168.x.x ranges) until configuration. DHCP is no solution since there might be no DHCP server in the field.

The devices would listen to UDP broadcasts and answer with broadcasts until they are given their new IP address this way.

This worked fine with Windows XP - but sucks with Windows 7: the config program does not receive the answer packets from the devices which still have 0.0.0.1. Wireshark sees the packets, then they are dumped by the system.

Question: Is there any *reason* (RFC?) that actually **prohibits** using this address in a local environment? Or is it just MS that was overcautious? *Where* can I read why they treat this address "invalid"? Which ranges are *really* "invalid" now, too?

Any idea of a workaround on the PC side (Win 7)?

I know that it is not recommended to use 0.xxx addresses for *work places*, but for this very reason - having a not-used address - it works perfectly.

Edit: there is a device out there called "Netburner" which might have faced the similar issue, according to their forum. See: http://forum.embeddedethernet.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=612&p=2198 Does - by coincidence - anybody know some background information?

Comment: Do you have that subnet in your network card configuration? Many systems will drop broadcast packets that come from a non-local subnet.

Comment: Could you switch to using Ethernet broadcast packets instead? It'd seem like removing the entire TCP/IP routing stack would be a benefit.

Comment: @thkala: we'll check this. thanks for the hint. Still - RFC1918 allows to use _any_ ip address locally, they only do not recommend it due to the drawbacks.

Comment: @minastaros: by non-local I mean subnets that are not in the same subnet as your computer. Blocking such broadcasts makes quite a bit of sense from a security standpoint.

Comment: @sarnold: oh, the devices are already in the field for a while. So switching would not so easy, new Win 7 PC software _should_ be able to deal with the "old" (=current) devices... What exacly do you have in mind, some kind of ARP ping stuff?

Comment: @minastaros, oh they are already deployed? Then Ethernet broadcasts won't work so well. I was thinking of setting up an ethernet broadcast group, having your devices broadcast to it, and your control application subscribe to that broadcast group. When they get an answer they can respond directly back to the device with a command to bring the little device up into IP land after negotiating an IP address with the local DHCP/bootp servers. But if they are already deployed, it's a bit late. :)

Comment: @thkala: sure, but I feel that blocking should be up to the firewall (which was switched off during investigation, just to add) -  and then there should be a way to unblock it if I really _want_ to receive these addresses. I thought that this is a _feature_ of UDP BCs, that you can reach addresses even outside the normal address space. Anyway, we will check if it would work with other adresses such as 4.0.0.1 or with any other address outside our own range.

Comment: @minastaros: you did try setting the PC to a 0.0.0.1/255.255.255.0 subnet with e.g. an 0.0.0.2 IP, right? And, BTW, it's quite possible that these packets are blocked at a lower level than the firewall...

Comment: @thkala: no, afaik the setup PC just has a "normal" 192.168.1.x. or something. When you say that they are blocked on a lower level, then I was interested why XP had no problem but Win 7 has. Who defines the rules for those "lower lewels", where can I, the user, read them? Even Microsoft should follow public rules (should...), and as long as 0.0.0.1 is not illegal according to any RFC or so I think they should not simply say "nope". -- Or am I totally wrong and have overseen something? Still open to learn...

Comment: @minastaros: I'll try to make it simple: Windows is doing the right thing. If your PC is _not_ in that subnet why the \*\*\*\* should it receive broadcasts from it? Just because it's in the same physical segment? Just add an additional IP address in the right subnet to the PC interface.

Comment: @ministaros: BTW, if your application wants to receive or send packets in foreign subnets, it should use raw sockets like Wireshark. Expecting the OS to pass on broadcast packets from foreign subnets to cooked sockets is IMHO broken behaviour - which is why they probably fixed it.

Comment: the idea behind the whole plot is to be able to find and configure devices of _any_ subnet (not only 0.0.0.1). Imagine the service technichian gets a device on his desk from anywhere out of the field and which is configured with an unkown Ip address. This way, we were able to contact it without using the screwdriver. There is surely lots of different other ways to do it (raw or ARP stuff). the thing is - it worked perfectly before (with Mac Os, Linux and XP PCs running the service software), and now we are facing restrictions which were not covered by rules we knew before.

Comment: @minastaros: Well, how about using wireshark to find the IP address of the device, and then configuring the PC to that specific subnet, as a workaround? Does that work?

Comment: Might be working as the PC can still _issue_ the broadcast messages. We're just passing the question to the technicians who will check. Then we'll know if the issue is related to the leading "0"-address range or, as you assume, to the different subnet. I will let you know. On the other hand - it is indeed only a workaround for testing and the "just in case-case". The service software application is not supposed to "work only with wireshark" and I doubt the IT-security department will give their blessings to that... ;-)

Comment: @thkala: have checked this: it did not work to switch the Windows PC's IP address to a 0.x.x.x one. So the workaround would not work as long as the devices still have 0.0.0.1.

Comment: @minastaros: do you have control over the source code of the application? How are you setting up to listen for those UDP packets? Would you be able to modify it to use raw sockets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as if your configuration application is listening for broadcast packets on all network interfaces and expecting to receive packets from foreign subnets.

That should *not* work - the OS should only pass-on broadcast packets from the subnets each network interface is on, not from all subnets on the same physical (e.g. Ethernet) segment. I am reasonably certain that doing otherwise is broken behaviour WRT the IP protocol.

The are two ways to deal with this:

- Make sure that your network interface has an IP address in the target subnet. You can have [more than one IP addresses](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722518.aspx) for each network card, so that should not interfere with normal network operations.
- Configure or modify you application to use raw sockets, like Wireshark. Keep in mind, however, that this overrides all normal checks and balances and should be avoided, since it can cause behaviour that is almost impossible to diagnose - which is why it is frowned upon by meny network administrators.

Comment: thkala, have many thanks for all your effort writing the answers. We will discuss your ideas and do some more tests. Using a different approach is probably possible and a way to think about for the future - however, the problem is that we cannot easily change all the devices which are already deployed. So from this standpoint the best solution was to stick with the same way and make it work somehow.
Concerning your 1st suggestion: according to my last comment above, we need to find devices from _any_ subnet. So adding an interface with 0.0.0.x will only do half the job. Anyway-thanks for that.

Comment: done some researches: first, tests showed that messages from a device with IP 1.0.0.1 _are_ received. Thus: **it is not a matter of the different subnet**. RFC922 clearly states in chapter 4 that "Broadcast to all hosts on the local hardware net" are possible, chapter 7 mentions receiver address 255.255.255.255. I conclude that when you can send _to_ all hosts, you must also be able to receive from them. The problem ist the leading 0.x. RFC1700 page 4 (b) says that 0.x.x.x are "Specified host on this network. Can only be used as a source address.". That's what we do - should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Can you you add new routing table entries to Windows machines easily? Windows has to know which interface to use when routing a broadcast packet to the `0.0.0.x` network.

The Unix machines I'm familiar with have a routing table that maps network/netmask entries to either gateways or interfaces (if the network is a local network). The local network (`192.168.0.0/16` for my home network) gets sent to interface `eth0`. Everything else `0.0.0.0/0` gets sent to a specific gateway machine `192.168.0.1`.

If my machine sent a UDP broadcast message to network `0.0.0.0/24` (in other words, UDP broadcast sent to `0.0.0.255`, then my machine would forward the packet to the gateway machine (which it can look up via arp). The switches in the middle wouldn't propagate the packet to other network devices, because the MAC address is set.

If my machine had another routing entry for `0.0.0.0/24` to the local interface, then my machine would send the packet on the wire using an ethernet broadcast group, and the switches would forward the packet to all connections. (Yay! Just like hubs in the 90s! :)

So I figure you need to add a routing entry for `0.0.0.0/24` to your client machines, so that they can properly address the broadcast packet.

Comment: The issue is not that the PC cannot _send_ the broadcasts. It can, but it does not _receive_ them. Actually, it does, because Wireshark sees them arriving, but then the app doesn't get it (and it did with XP).